# Using Moveit with Real Robot (UR5)

Tags: rviz, moveit, ur5

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello ROS Users,
I am interested to know if anyone has tried using Moveit with a Real Robot, UR5 to be more specific. If yes, what changes have to be done to the launch file/s generated by running the below command:

```
$ roslaunch planning_environment planning_description_configuration_wizard.launch urdf_package:=<robot package> urdf_path:=<urdf path relative to package>
```

I am using ROS groovy, running on Ubuntu 12.04.Also, As I understand, The launch files are generated for ROS fuerte and for groovy the process is not automated. Anyone who has worked on this, please share the details.

Regards,
Murali

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/101741/using-moveit-with-real-robot-(ur5)/) by [MKI](https://answers.ros.org/users/8136/mki/) on ROS Answers with karma: 246 on 2013-11-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The latest source version of the UR5 (groovy and hydro) has moveit support.  It can be found [here](https://github.com/ros-industrial/universal_robot/tree/groovy-devel/ur5_moveit_config).

This package is not set up by default to communicate with the hardware.  This can be added by following this [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/Industrial/Tutorials/Create_a_MoveIt_Pkg_for_an_Industrial_Robot).

NOTE: The UR driver supports the joint trajectory action directly, so the steps in section 4.1 Required Topics/Services are a little different.  You will still need to create a launch file that launches the UR driver node (with the appropriate IP address).

EDIT

Apparently the correct launch file already exists in the latest versions.  Simply run:

roslaunch ur5_moveit_config moveit_planning_execution.launch sim:=false robot_ip:=IP_OF_THE_ROBOT

---

Originally posted by [sedwards](https://answers.ros.org/users/78/sedwards/) with karma: 1601 on 2013-11-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0